# SCSS formatter for angular 5

Tags: angular, sass

In our angular 5.2 project, we keep getting the below errors in scss files,

[image: SCSS erros related to spaces]

do we have a VS code plugin OR a Scss formatter which can take care these space issues in the scss??

Comment: I use Angular Extension pack,which includes I think every library needed for angular .

Comment: I think, it just includes prettier and that is optional ( you need to install it explicitly) but yes, it is a good option for most of your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use SCSS Formatter by Sibiraj in VS Code, just run SHIFT + ALT + F or right click and 'format document', to format the document

Comment: Yeah, I saw that plugin as well. But unfortunately my company has blocked pretty-much any plugin to be added in my VS code. but I will check this. +1 for your effort. Thanks.

Comment: Dang that's a bummer. Hope you find a solution soon!

Answer (score 1):

These errors seem to be from the `stylelint` linting tool. You'll have to either modify your `stylelint` config and turn off these rules or you have to fix them in your `scss` file.

To help you with detecting these errors on VS code as you code, you can use an extension.

1. Go to `View > Extensions`.
2. Search for a `stylelint` extension (Recommendation: `shinnn.stylelint` by Shinnosuke Watanabe).
3. Install the extension.

Now open your `scss` file and VS code should indicate your lint errors. (This might require you to restart VS code).

Comment: you are right. it is coz of Stylelint. Seems my company has blocked this extension to be added in the VS code.  for now, I removed all the spaces manually but it sucks and do not want to this again manually.  I will check with the admin team in this. Thank You .

Answer (score 0):

Do you copy/paste the scss code? and are you sure that what you copy was a scss code? sass codes does not have comas in the end of the line; maybe its not compiling because its not a scss code, my hint is that many EOL errors you getting

```
.some-class {
    display: none;
    .some-other-class {
        background-color: green;
    }
}
```

this is a scss code.
please put more detail in the question.